# ffmpeg merge silent video with another video+audio

Tags: audio, video, filter, merge, ffmpeg

I want to create, in a single command, a video from 3 sources:

1. a silent background video;
2. a smaller video to be overlayed (same length of 1), KEEPING its AUDIO;
3. a PNG logo to be overlayed

I can create the video but cannot get the audio track. I don't understand if `-vf` is supposed to work in this case. This is what I've tried to do :

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i MASTER_SILENT_VIDEO.mp4 -vf "movie=SMALLER_VIDEO_WITH_AUDIO.flv, scale=320:-1[inner];movie=MY_LOGO.png[inner2]; [in][inner] overlay=800:480,amerge [step1]; [step1][inner2] overlay=30:30 [out]" completed.mp4
```

The "amerge" filter should do the audio merging job, but of course it doesn't work. I've found similar questions involving `-map` or filtergraph but they refer to mixing a video source and an audio source; I tried several filtergraph examples without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## overlay one video over other using audio from one input

Use `-filter_complex`, eliminate the *movie* source filters, and explicitly define output streams with `-map`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i overlay_with_audio.flv -i logo.png -filter_complex
"[1:v]scale=320:-1[scaled];
 [0:v][scaled]overlay=800:480[bg];
 [bg][2:v]overlay=30:30,format=yuv420p[video]"
-map "[video]" -map 1:a -movflags +faststart
output.mp4
```

You may have to provide additional options to the [overlay filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) depending on the length of the inputs and how you want overlay to react, but because you did not provide the complete console output from your command I had to make a generic, less efficient, and possibly incorrect example.

## overlay one video over other merging audio from both inputs

```
ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i overlay_with_audio.flv -i logo.png -filter_complex
"[1:v]scale=320:-1[scaled];
 [0:v][scaled]overlay=800:480[bg];
 [bg][2:v]overlay=30:30,format=yuv420p[video];
 [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[audio]"
-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -ac 2 -movflags +faststart
output.mp4
```

I'm assuming both inputs are stereo and that you want a stereo output. Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio channel Manipulation - 2 × stereo → stereo](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a2stereostereo).

Comment: Regarding your answer, if the first video (main.mp4 in your example) had sound too and I would like to retain both audios in the two, what would change in the ffmpeg command ?

Comment: Perfect again, infinite thanks. I'm trying to understand ffmpeg documentation but it's still a bit hard for me. I'll dig deeper !